# Which version of Gapps to install for Lineage?

Tags: google-apps, lineageos

I am going to install Lineage and I need to decide which version of open Gapps to use.

I use lots of Google apps (Google Play Store, Gmail, Calendar, Photos, Music, Google search, Translate, Keep etc.). But, I am fine with installing them one by one, from Google Play store. So, I prefer a minimalist version so that, I don't need to keep anything that I don't use. Therefore, my first thought was Pico Gapps. But, this version does not include offline speech recognition files. Can these be installed later from the google store? Or, if I want to be able to use the "ok google" voice command, do I need to install Nano Gapps?

Also, are there any other obstacles I am not aware of? I want to be able to install anything else from the play store (and not to be forced to flash anything later).

Comment: I voted to close this because it's got a heavy title, the most upvoted answer shows that people aren't finding it for your workload. A better title would be "What version of Google Apps should I install if I just want to bootstrap the playstore", which is obviously the smallest one.

Answer (score 13):

You can download Gapps package for your lineage from this website source [opengapps.org](http://opengapps.org/).
Site contains several fields such as :

### 1.Platforms:

- **ARM64** - For 64-bit devices

  ARM64 means the devices that are running 64 bit operating system/processor.
- **ARM** - For 32-bit Devices

ARM means the device that are running 32 bit operating system/processor.

- **x86**
  for Intel Smartphones like Zenphone .
- **x86_64**
  This is a very uncommon, these are used in some android emulators.

  You can check your device's ARM using this [Antutu link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antutu.ABenchMark)

### 2.Android versions:

- **14.0** Android U (Upside Down Cake)
- **13.0** Android T (Tiramisu)
- **12.0** Android S (Snow Cone)
- **11.0** Android R (Red Velvet Cake)
- **10.0** Android Q (Quince Tart)
- **9.0** Pie (Pistachio Ice Cream)
- **8.1, 8.0** Oreo
- **7.1, 7.0** Nougat
- **6.0** Marshmallow
- **5.1, 5.0** Lollipop (Opengapps supported up to Lollipop in 2019)
- **4.4** KitKat.(Opengapps supported up to KitKat in 2018)

### 3.Variant:

- **Aroma**: Graphical installer of the super package while in recovery menu, `it allows user to select which applications to install.`
- **Super**: Includes all Google Apps that were ever shipped on a Google device.
- **Stock**: Recommended package that contains all Google Apps that come standard on latest Nexus/Pixel phone.
- **Full** : Very similar to Stock version.
- **Mini** : Smaller set of popular Google Apps with extra functionality.
- **Micro**: Limited set of Google Apps with Gmail, Calendar Google Now with extra functionality.
- **Nano** : Minimal installation with extra functionality.
- **Pico** : Minimum with Google Play functionality.
  (Each package varies with file sizes and included Google Apps)

Your `/system` folder capacity decides which version is suited for you.
You can check your capacity using this app [Disk Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo&hl=en). Then select your Gapps variant, and install it. And, I would recommend Aroma so that you can decide which apps to be installed during installation at recovery.(**N.B:Aroma had issues with some recovery versions, but, it worked on TWRP 3.0.2 on my redmi 1s)**.

**Note**: **Please mention which is your device**. I have tried pico version in my Redmi 1S, because of lesser system capacity(Pico version includes apps like Google Play and Google Play Services). There after, I installed Google app as user app(from play store) and can run 'OK Google' voice command.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest the Pico version for the specific platform you have. It gives you the ability to access google where you can download only the apps that you need or want.