# Installing Lineage OS 13 on Mi Pad

Tags: root-access, rom-flashing, twrp, tablet, xiaomi

I am planning to install Lineage OS 13 on my MiPad (1st gen) running MIUI7.

I was told that the first thing i need to do for this is install a custom recovery like TWRP & resize the partition as per [this guide](http://en.miui.com/thread-118294-1-1.html).

I have a few questions

1) Do I first need to root my MiPad before installing TWRP? If so, how do I do that?

2) I found that I could install TWRP from the play store - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.twrp.twrpapp
(This is version 1.15)

How the guide says I should download TWRP_multirom-v2.8.4-mocha.zip Recovery. It doesn't mention where from but the version seems to 2.8.4

Why does the playstore contain such an old version? And where do I get TWRP_multirom-v2.8.4-mocha.zip from?

The guide also says 
    Change the Mi Recovery to either CWM or TWRP Recovery (I used TWRP)

What does this mean & how do I do this?

Comment: What you see on Playstore is not the custom recovery, but a helper app to install the recovery (if your device is rooted). Don't confuse the two :) You can also install TWRP by flashing it via [fastboot](/tags/fastboot/info). No root required, but the [bootloader](/tags/bootloader/info) must be unlocked. Before you ask: I cannot give you device-specific info as I have no Mi Pad.

Answer (score 2):

To install Lineage OS 13 on your Mi Pad, requires these steps.

**N.B: Rooting voids your warranty and may brick your device. Backup your device data before any operations. Kindly read the steps given on xda several times and perform operation.**

1. Required to Root your Mi pad. [MIUI Root zip](http://en.miui.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=184413&highlight=root%2Bzip)

   Download the zip file, place it on internal memory, go to updater app and flash the zip by selecting it from internal memory. your device got rooted.
   To unroot, download stock rom from miui and flash it.
2. Install a custom recovery TWRP(recommended) or CWM. [TWRP download](https://twrp.me/xiaomi/xiaomimipad.html)

   Download twrp app or zip file from the above link, if from app, open app, it will ask root permissions, provide them, select your device, and install the version provided for your device.
3. Lineage OS 13 ROM zip file. [Lineage zip](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-pad)

   - XDA contains several discussions about rooting, installing custom recovery(twrp), custom rom(Lineage, resurrection remix etc.). Please go through every aspect about the steps and then follow it.
   - Try to download any official rom, if not download unofficial that updated to latest version.
4. Google apps for marshmallow. [opengapps](http://opengapps.org/)

   download google apps for your

   - platform arm(32bit), arm64(64bit)
   - android version, lineage 13 is marshmallow(6.0)
   - variant based [please look this answer for which-version-of-gapps-to-install-for-lineage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180142/which-version-of-gapps-to-install-for-lineage/180145#180145)

If you can go to mi recovery using power and volume button, your bootloader is unlocked.
[unlock steps mipad2](http://en.miui.com/thread-203226-1-1.html)

Comment: ` If you can go to mi recovery using power and volume button, your bootloader is unlocked.` - I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Do you have an MiPad - have you tried installing Lineage OS on it?

Comment: Is MiPad arm32 or arm64? Is there a way to figure out?

Comment: `To unroot, search miui forum for unroot zip.` - why would someone want to do this - can rooting cause issues?

Comment: power off your device, press volume up and power button. if it loads to mi recovery, your boot loader is unlocked, that means your can modify, install any operations of device.

Comment: How will I know if it loads to mi recovery - what will that look like? And how would the bootloader got unlocked without my knowing it?

Comment: rooting gives you permission to modify device's system files

Comment: I am asking why would I want to unroot not why would I want to root.

Comment: it was written mi recovery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65401/discussion-between-rahul-gopi-and-user93353).

Comment: Well, the first step itself failed. I downloaded the root zip. Went to updater & selected it. Right away, I got an error message "Update failed. Can't update at the moment. Touch OK to report this error to our engineers"

Comment: may these links help you: http://en.miui.com/thread-158213-1-1.html, http://xiaomiadvices.com/root-miui-8-mi-redmi-phones/, https://medium.com/@md_ray/how-to-root-xiaomi-mi-pad-using-stock-recovery-and-developer-rom-flashing-update-zip-not-using-2064427350b3,http://en.miui.com/thread-30617-1-1.html