# Which Gapps package should I use..?

Tags: applications

I am using Lava Iris x8 mobile. I am going to flash lineage(6.0.1) custom rom .Which gapps package should I download...?

[image]

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180142/which-version-of-gapps-to-install-for-lineage/180145#180145

Answer (score 1):

In oder to know what gapps you should use, you should have the following in mind:

1. Your android version, 6.0 for the ROM you going to flash
2. How much functionality of gapps you need ( for most basic case which is Playstore then pico variant should be enough but if you need more apps you can install more extensive variants e.g nano, micro, mini, full etc. so long as your system partition has enough capacity to handle that file size)
3. Your smartphone's chipset architecture and bits, checking specs for [Lava Iris x8 mobile](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/lava-iris-x8-2372) shows that it runs on Mediatek MT6592 again checking for [MT6592](https://www.mediatek.com/products/smartphones/mt6592) specs on Mediatek's website it shows that it is a 32-bit ARM chipset.

So for your case; Platform=ARM, Android=6.0, you can choose any variant depending on the amount of gapps you want and you phones capacity