# Does LineageOS allow us to install apps via Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store, lineageos, google-apps

Someone told me we can't install Google apps after installing LineageOS and it doesn't support Google Play.

What is the truth behind this? Can I access Google Play in LineageOS?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180142/which-version-of-gapps-to-install-for-lineage/180145#180145

Answer (score 16, accepted):

LineageOS is Open Source OS. Google apps like Play Store, Gmail, Maps etc are proprietary Google products and cannot be bundled with LineageOS due to licencing issues.

However, you can always download these **G**oogle **A**pps **P**ackages (Gapps) to run with LineageOS. These come in different flavors, starting with minimal Google services to full fledged suite of Google Apps . For more details see [LineageOS Wiki](https://wiki.lineageos.org/gapps.html). Related [Which version of Gapps to install for Lineage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/180142/131553)

So, LineageOS by itself does not have Google Play  but by installing Gapps of your choice, you can have Google Play and other Google apps of your choice.

Comment: To add to this, you have the option of flashing a .zip file of Gapps in recovery mode (at any time). It's usually less than 200MB. I'd recommend the smallest "lite" flavour which gives you the Play Store and other basics.